# Multiple properties to one person Semantic Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am new to Semantic mediawiki and it seems a great tool to me. I was looking for a way how to asign multiple properties to a person in a text on mediawiki. For example:

I do this: [[Name::John]]  But I want to assign also the property to John:  Gender::Male, Haircolor::Red, Height::180

How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks halfer for correcting. I am from Holland so it is not my mothertongue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [subobjects](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Adding_subobjects) :

```
{{#subobject:
|Has name=John
|Has height=180
...
}}
```

Comment: Ah great thanks for your answer. So i have to do it this way?
[[Name::John]] (to disply the name John in the text Followed by
{{#subobject:
|Has name=John
|Has height=180
...
}}
or is their an other way to do?

Comment: It really depends on the purpose of your wiki, and how you will use your data. The correct approach in a semantic system would be to create a separate person page, ideally in a specific namespace, which will hold all data for the person, and then have an aggregating property from the content page, like [[Has related person::Person:John]], so you should provide more description of what you want to do if you want relevant advises.